# Set a Maximum Value in a Calcul

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

The question I am going to ask is going to sound really really stupid but I am struggling to find a way to do it.

I am making a calculator for my company.
In my calcul, I would like that the maximum value displayed don't exceed 120.

Ex:

```
12*2= 24
12*10= 120
12*97403= 120
```

I know it just missing something ridiculous in my code but i can't find the solution on internet.
I am just a newbie who is struggling to me honest ! haha

I give you what I have done.
If you can take 20 seconds to tell me what I have to add I would be more than grateful. :)

My code is:
h.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController    
{    
    IBOutlet UITextField *pourcent;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ans;
    IBOutlet UITextField *heuresdif;
    IBOutlet UITextField *heuresacquises;
    IBOutlet UILabel *DIF;
    IBOutlet UILabel *MONTANT;        
}    
-(IBAction)calculator;
-(IBAction)clean;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;    
@end
```

and the m.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)calculator {
float a = ([ans.text floatValue]);
float b = ([pourcent.text floatValue]);
float c = ([heuresdif.text floatValue]);
float d = ([heuresacquises.text floatValue]);

// Heures de DIFF Restant
float f = (a*20*b/100)-c+d;

// Montant du DIF
float g = f*9.53;

DIF.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", f];

MONTANT.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.2f", g]; 
}
-(IBAction)clean {
  ans.text = @"";
  pourcent.text = @"";
  heuresdif.text = @"";
  heuresacquises.text = @"";
}
@end
```

Comment: Sorry I meant 12*2=24 obviously! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the value before changing the label on your .m file.

You should do something like that:

```
 if(myValue >= 120)
   myLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", myValue]
 else
   myLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", myMaxValue]
```